# Discord.JS Purge.js command issue

Tags: module, discord.js, fs

Ok so my bot got rebuilt with a somewhat different code.

I'm using a somewhat more simplified `fs` command and events handler. My command works as intended.

But I'm wanting to add the amount pruned into the fields for the richEmbed and it keeps erroring out.

Here is my `purge.js` file

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports = {
    name: 'purge',
    description: 'Purge up to 99 messages.',
    execute(message, args) {
        console.log("purging messages")


        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("Success")
            .setColor(0x00AE86)
            .setFooter("Guardian", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
            .setThumbnail("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setURL("https://github.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/tree/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian")
            .addField("Bot Messages Purged", "missing code here", false)
            .addField("User Pins Purged", "missing code here", false)
            .addField("User Messages Purged", "missing code here", false)
            .addField("Total Messages Purged", "missing code here", false)

        message.channel.send({ embed });

        const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;

        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            return message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid number.');
        } else if (amount <= 1 || amount > 100) {
            return message.reply('you need to input a number between 1 and 99.');
        }

        message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send('there was an error trying to prune messages in this channel!');
        });
    },
};
```

If it helps this i my `index.js`

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { token } = require('./token.json');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    console.log(file,command)
}

fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
        if(!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
        const eventFunction = require(`./events/${file}`);
        console.log(eventFunction)
        eventFunction.execute(client)
    });
});

client.login(token);
```

and this is my `message.js`

```js
const { prefix } = require('./prefix.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'message',
    description: '',
    execute:function(client) {
        client.on('message',message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

        try {
            client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
                }
})

}};
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out what to place into the `"missing code here"` sections. Also any way to lock it to people with Administrator permissions only would be useful as well. I attempted that but it failed to work with the embed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to know how to get the amount of the purged pins, bot msgs and user msgs. For this you need to put your embed after you deleted the messages.

**purge.js**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports = {
    name: 'purge',
    description: 'Purge up to 99 messages.',
    execute(message, args) {
        console.log("purging messages")

        const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;

        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            return message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid number.');
        } else if (amount <= 1 || amount > 100) {
            return message.reply('you need to input a number between 1 and 99.');
        }

        message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).then(deletedMessages => {
            // Filter the deleted messages with .filter()
            var botMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.author.bot);
            var userPins = deletedMessages.filter(m => m.pinned);
            var userMessages = deletedMessages.filter(m => !m.author.bot);

            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle("Success")
                .setColor(0x00AE86)
                .setFooter("Guardian", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
                .setThumbnail("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setURL("https://github.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/tree/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian")
                .addField("Bot Messages Purged", botMessages.size, false)
                .addField("User Pins Purged", userPins.size, false)
                .addField("User Messages Purged", userMessages.size, false)
                .addField("Total Messages Purged", deletedMessages.size, false);

            message.channel.send(embed);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send('there was an error trying to prune messages in this channel!');
        });
    },
};
```